# How to interpret results of Mlxtend's association rule

Tags: python-3.x, mlxtend, fpgrowth

I am using `mlxtend` to find association rules:

Here is the code:

```
df = apriori(dum_data, min_support=0.4, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(df, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)
rules2=rules[ (rules['lift'] >= 1) & (rules['confidence'] >= 0.7) ]
```

Output:

```
antecedents             consequents    antecedentsupport    consequentsupport   support confidence  lift      leverage  conviction
frozenset({'C'})        frozenset({'B'})        0.63        0.705                   0.45    0.726   1.030       0.013   1.077
frozenset({'A'})        frozenset({'B'})        0.98        0.705                   0.69    0.70    1.003       0.0007  1.00081
frozenset({'A', 'C'})   frozenset({'B'})        0.63        0.705                   0.45    0.72    1.030       0.013   1.0776
```

I have given a `min support=0.4`.  What is the difference between `antecedentsupport`, `consequentsupport` and `support`?

What do mean by `lift and leverage?` How to judge if its good or bad?

Confidence I can understand that is how many times `C` and `B` occured together for first rule in output. ? Is that correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take the third rule `({A,C} => {B})` as an example:

support = support of {A, B, C} | support means, that you count the number of transactions that contain all three of {A, B, C} and divide it by the total number of transactions.

antecedentsupport = support of what precedes the `=>`, means support of {A,C}

consequentsupport   = support of what comes after the `=>`, means support of {B}

confidence = how likely is it, that after we observed {A,C} that the transaction additionally contains {B}. Think of it as the conditional probability `p(B given {A,C})`.

Lift: The definition for lift can e.g. be found here: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(data_mining)). This means, that if lift < 1 then {A,C} and {B} occur together less often than expected. If lift is larger than one then {A,C} and {B} appear together more often than expected.

Leverage is roughly the same. It also compares the expected co-occurrence and the observed one. Further explanation e.g. [here](https://support.bigml.com/hc/en-us/articles/207310225-What-is-the-difference-between-lift-and-leverage-)

What makes a good lift/leverage is subjective but I'd suggest a lift of > 1. If it comes to rules I would look more at confidence.